# Стили css появляются только при предпросмотре в Битрикс 24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

На сайте мне приходится менять стили компонентов некоторых блоков. Почему то стили в предпросмотре меняются и все как надо, но в зоне редактора ничего не меняется в чем дело?